# Variable losing original value after a new instance is manipulated

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js, and am having an issue when it comes to my variables losing their original value after manipulating a copy.

For example:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = array1;
array2[0] = null;
```

If I then inspect these values, `array2` is correct, but `array1` has the same set as `array2`, even though I haven't touched `array1`.

I'm seeing it happen here, too.

```
function func(inputArray) {
    var outputArray = inputArray;
    outputArray[0] = null;
    return outputArray;
}
var array3 = [4,5,6,7];
var array4 = func(array3);
```

Here, `array3` is getting overwritten to what `array4` is.

How do I get around this?

Comment: array2 is a pointer to array1. That C terminology is actually completely correct for saying what happens in Javascript when accessing non-simple variables. You need to "deep-clone" objects (which arrays are) if you want a true copy. Just like in C.

Comment: You need to clone it. Whether it's deep doesn't matter in this case because the elements of the array are all primitives anyway (ie not objects/arrays, which are reference types). There may be other cases where they're reference types but it still doesn't matter, and still others where it does matter and shallow clone is the correct way. In the cases where it doesn't matter, you should use shallow clone for performance reasons. In short, don't believe the catch-all advice that "You need to \"deep-clone\" objects ... if you want a true copy." - A.B's shallow clone is fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing this line

```
  var array2 = array1;
```

Both array2 and array1 points to same array. Changes in 1 array will automatically update other.As arrays in js are an object and objects are always passed or are assigned by reference.

What you can do here is as an hack

```
var array2 = array1.slice()
```

or

```
var array2 = [].concat(array1);
```